# Executing python script with flask, from button

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to execute a def/python script from flask, when clicked on button... but can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my Python Code

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
import webbrowser
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

def contact():
    if "open" in request.form:
        print("Test")
    elif "close" in request.form:
        print("Test 2")
    return render_template('contact.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is my HTML Code

````
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% extends "base.html" %}
        {% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <input type="submit" name="open" value="Open">
        <input type="submit" name="close" value="Close">
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: You should take a look at the `subprocess` module

Comment: Please make sure your HTML `input`s are inside HTML [form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: Can you please elaborate about what behaviour you expect? Also, what is your question?

Comment: @Arek'Fu I want to when I click the btn, it activates forexample phillips hue lights... all already have that part of the code figured out in a diffrent script... but I can't get it to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is in `{% block content %}` but you need to have a `form` in order to call backend where you provide the url route that you want to call and the method you want to use (usually with forms it's `POST`). Also in the `/contact` endpoint you need to provide `@app.route('/contact')` and that it would accept `POST` request `@app.route('/contact', methods=['POST'])`. Modify your python and HTML to look like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, jsonify
import webbrowser
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/contact', methods=['POST'])
def contact():
    result = False
    if "open" in request.form:
        result = activate_lamp()  # expecting True as a result of function
    elif "close" in request.form:
        result = deactivate_lamp()
    return jsonify({'result': result})  # expecting True as a result of function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="open" value="Open">
            <input type="submit" name="close" value="Close">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `jsonify` will return an object to the front end with default `200` response code. Then you can either do something with it or ignore it. The idea is that in the route you can call other functions, but you must return a valid HTTP response to the front-end, e.g. `jsonify`, or plain `return '', 200` might be enough.

Comment: I don't want it to open a new site, I want to forexample turn off phillips hue lights, i have that part of the code working.